# Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'starColor' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I'm using xamarin.
i've already tried to change the "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android" but it didn't work. I changed the build target but the error still...
this is the xml code where the error persist:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>                
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#4A6EA9" android:starColor="#4A6EA9"/>
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</item> 
</selector>
```

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="false">
  <layer-list>
   <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
     <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
     <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>    
    </shape>
   </item>

Answer (score 1):

`android:starColor` - No Such attribute in android

It should be `android:startColor`